# How can characters " \n \t \r " be replaced with '-'?

Tags: php, regex

How can characters " \n \t \r " be replaced  with '-' ?

```
echo preg_replace('/\s/','-','\n\t\n\r\n');//output '\n\t\n\r\n' instead should be'-----'
```

Edit: I have dynamic content in real app like:

```
 preg_replace('/\s/','-',$_Request['content']);
```

can I fix it by adding "" around variable?

```
preg_replace('/\s/','-',"$_Request['content']");
```

Edit2:

**How can be string converted from format 'str' to format "str"?**

Thanks

Comment: If you are receiving them from `$_GET`, wouldn't your existing `preg_replace()` work?

Comment: lets say i have regular string in format '' how  can he converted to "" format? (I playing with string that have a lot function before)

Comment: The way PHP works, that's just impossible to do. Are you sure you are getting the correct whitespace characters?

Comment: Please don't spam comments, it just adds noise to the page. We can see your edits without your "please see my edit" comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, two things.  First, the problem is single quotes in your replacement string.  Meta-Characters (`\n\t\r`, etc) are not processed inside of single quotes.

However, don't use a regex for this.  There's no need for the complexity of the regex.  Use

Either use [`str_replace`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
echo str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t", "\v"), '-', "\r\n\t\r\v\n\t");
```

Or [`strtr`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
echo strtr("\r\n\t\r\v\n\t", "\r\n\t\v", '----');
```

**Edit:** Ahh, now I see what you're getting at.  You have a string with a literal `\r\n\t\r\v\n\t` in it, and want to replace them out.  Well, you can do that via regex:

```
$regex = '/(\s|\\\\[rntv]{1})/';
$string = preg_replace($regex, '-', $_GET['content']);
```

Basically, it matches any space character, and any literal `\` followed by either `r`, `n`, `t` or `v`...

Comment: Thanks! why not just : $regex = '/(\\\\\[rnt]{1})/';

Comment: @Yosef: Because that will ignore literal linefeeds and tags in the result.  It depends on exactly what you're trying to do (Which has been hard to tell).  But that will work if you're just trying to replace literal occurances of `\n` in a string...

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to replace the actual whitespace characters, you need to enclose the input string in double quotes (`"`) so PHP converts the escape sequences for you:

```
echo preg_replace('/\s/', '-', "\n\t\n\r\n");
```

Else if the escape sequences occur literally (i.e. you see `\n\t\n\r\n` instead of line feed, tab, line feed, carriage return, line feed), you need to replace by the following character class (and keep single quotes (`'`) on the input string):

```
echo preg_replace('/\\\\[rnt]/', '-', '\n\t\n\r\n');
```

You ought to be passing `content` through `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, I don't know how PHP handles tabs, newlines and returns in GET variables.

Comment: @Flying Swissman: It wasn't there before, but I snuck it in to see if anyone would notice :)

Comment: let say it not $_Get it $_Request (can be $_Post or $_Get)

Comment: You need to double-escape the ` \\ ` in the edited version to ` \\\\ `.  See [it in action](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=653)...

Answer (score 2):

You are using `'`s instead of `"`s. You should change your code to:

```
echo preg_replace('/\s/','-',"\n\t\n\r\n");
```

See here: single-quoted and double-quoted.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

There's also a string method for that:

```
echo strtr($str, "\r\n\t\v ", "-----");
```

If you want to remove linebreaks but retain spaces, then remove the trailing  and the fifth `-`.

---

Since you seemingly want literal `\r` and `\n` converted, you need to use a map (or even a regex) like:

```
echo strtr($str, array('\\r'=>"\r", '\\n'=>"\n", '\t'=>"\t", ' '=>"␣"));
// single quoted strings escaped twice for illustration
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo preg_replace('/\s/','-',"\n\t\n\r\n");
```

Note the double quotes on the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose a string with single quotes, special characters lose their special meaning:

```
echo preg_replace('/\s/','-',"\n\t\n\r\n");
```